# User-specified positioning of caption

Tags: captions, positioning

For tuning reasons that I cannot detail here, I would like to be able to control the position of the `caption` of figures. My current code is as follows:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\colorbox{red!10}{%
\parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
\centering\includegraphics{fig1}%
\caption{}%
\label{fig:ch1-1}}}%
\end{figure}
```

Is is possible to move the caption (which is here only Figure 1) to the top-left corner of the `colorbox`. I know that the `float` package offers similar possibilities but would like to know if there is a solution by hand.

Comment: Inside the `\colorbox` or outside and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a marginal alternative to [Herbert's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27568/user-positoning-of-caption/27571#27571) that preserves some of the original vertical/horizontal spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \colorbox{red!10}{%
    \parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
      \captionsetup{format=plain,singlelinecheck=false}
      \caption{}\label{fig:ch1-1} \removelastskip\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\abovecaptionskip\relax}
      \centering\includegraphics{fig1}%
    }%
  }%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Colorbox figure with caption top-left]

Moving the `\caption` to above the `\includegraphics` places the caption above the image. The `demo` package option to `graphicx` is merely for illustration.

Comment: what about being on the top left without being above (ie no extra vertical space)?

Comment: @pluton: I've updated my answer to reflect this adjustment. The vertical space is reverse using `-\baselineskip-10pt` where `10pt` is the standard space between figure and caption (taken from the [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf)).

Comment: Better use `\abovecaptionskip` instead of 10pt, or simply set `\abovecaptionskip` to 0pt before `\caption`.

Comment: the caption is still over the image when it is longer than the left side of the image.

Comment: @Axel: Thanks; I originally tried `\belowcaptionskip`.

Answer (score 4):

You can cretae a new macro for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\def\Caption#1{\refstepcounter{figure}Figure~\thefigure: #1}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\colorbox{red!10}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    \Caption{\label{fig:ch1-1}}\hfill
    \raisebox{-\height+0.7\baselineskip}{\includegraphics{image}}}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your minipages cannot be avoided?

Comment: @pluton: sure, but then the caption cannot be longer than one line.

Comment: yes this is true. In this special case of interest, there will be no `fooo`. Thanks

Comment: then you also do not need the caption package, see edit